# Selecting lines occupying identical positions in MapInfo or QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, query, line

I have two shapefiles from a client, one is their entire network (complete with unique IDs) and another a selection I need. However the selection file does not have unique IDs but the entire one does. How would I be able to select the lines that appear in both files from the entire network shapefile?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mapinfo you should try this methods.

### method (Intersects)

Copy this SQL code in some text editor. Replace table names (*table1* and *table2*) with your tables (where first table is a entire network with IDs and second one is a partial) and save it with extension .QRY.

```
Fields {*}
Tables {table1, table2}
Where {table1.Obj Intersects table2.Obj}
Group {}
Order {}
Into {Selection}
```

Then, in MapInfo go to menu **QUERY/SQL Select...** (or press ALT+Q and again press Q)
Now you are in SQL Select editor. Click on **LOAD TEMPLATE** and load QRY file.

Check again with **Verify** and click **OK**.
You should get all lines from *table1* that intersects *table2*

### method (creating a Buffer)

Select all objects from Table2.
Then create a buffer around it > **Objects/Buffer…**

- enter some small value in “Value” (0.2meters)
- choose “One buffer for each object”

In next dialog (Data Aggregation) set 'Aggregation Method' all to “Value” then **OK**.

You have now a small buffer around each object in table2.

Now create like in previous example a QRY file and run it:

```
Fields {*}
Tables {table1, table2}
Where {table1.Obj Entirely Within table2.Obj}
Group {}
Order {}
Into {selection}
```

You should get all lines from *table1* that intersects *table2*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) If the answer work for you: you can "accepted" the answer (click the grey checkmark at the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS do: Vector->Spatial Query and set the query to 'Intersects'.  This may also select the lines that just touch the ends of your sub-set geometry.  In ArcGIS this would be 'Select by Location' but I am not familiar with MapInfo.  Using PostGIS through the QGIS interface will give you more control over the select-by-location operation.

The alternative is to do a Spatial Join of your geometry with the attributes on the geometry without (in QGIS do: Vector->Data Management->Join Attributes by location.  This will put all the attributes back into the 'selection' shapefile.

...or... (in GIS there is ALWAYS at least half a dozen ways of doing something) if the geometries are identical for the features you want (i.e. the sub-set is not clipped), you could make a 'selection-id' field in each shapefile based on a string concatenated from the x and y coordinates of the central coordinate (which should be safe for a road network - or you could do some combination of the start and end point geometries).  Then simply do a table join and discard anything which doesn't match.  This last approach will be completely GIS-software independent and would get you round any issues with the free way in which QGIS implements select by intersection.